# floating dose behind the boat

Tags: meaning

I am reading 'The old man and the sea.'
I've read this sentence as follows.
'But the bird was almost out of sight now and nothing showed on the surface of the water but some patches of yellow, sun-bleached Sargasso weed and the purple, formalized, iridescent, gelatinous bladder of a Portuguese man-of-war floating **dose** beside the boat.'

In this, What's the meaning of 'dose'? In dictionary I have, It only is remarked as 'a measured amount of it which is intended to be taken at one time.'
With this meaning, I can't make sense of above sentence. please help me.:)

Comment: This is an OCR or transcription error— unfortunate, as it is a somewhat famous sentence. The purple, formalized, iridescent, gelatinous bladder of a Portuguese man-of-war was floating **close** beside the boat.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typographical error

Comment: or maybe it wasn't a typographical error, it was just a poorly legible font where the c and the l ran too close together.  The importance of typography!  =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Choster said in his comment, this is an error in your edition. You can see the line here, in its first publication, in the September 1, 1952 issue of *Life* magazine:

[The Old Man and the Sea](http://books.google.com/books?id=WVYEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA39&dq=%22Portuguese%20man-of-war%20floating%20close%20beside%20the%20boat%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=VaZiU7jyKpKbyAT784HAAg&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22Portuguese%20man-of-war%20floating%20close%20beside%20the%20boat%22&f=false)

It should be:

> ...**close** beside the boat.

Comment: Oh my god. I have very deplorable, poor edition. I would like to burn it, and buy new one.:(